# how to find next Node in preOrder traverse recursively

Tags: java, tree, preorder

I want to write a function which takes a node of tree. It should return what is the next Node visited after the taken node in preOrder.
I have written this Code:
(This code searches for the left child and returns it. If the temp has no left child but it has right child this function returns right one. but if the Node is a leaf and has no child it gets parents until get a node that has right child.)

```
    public Node fineNextPreOrder(Node temp)
    {
    if(temp.left!=null)
        return temp.left;
    else if((temp.left==null)&&(temp.right!=null))
        return temp.right;
    else if((temp.left==null)&&(temp.right==null))
    {
        while((temp!=root)&&(!((temp.parent.left!=null)&&(temp.parent.left==temp)&&(temp.parent.right!=null))))
            temp = temp.parent;
        if(temp != root)
            return temp.parent.right;
    }

        return null;

}
```

It works true but I want to make it recursive.

can Any one please help me with this??

Thanks in advance for your Attention.

Comment: No, It's preOrder. for example you should find the node that comes after the root in preOrder traverse then you should take a look that if the root has left child then the next node is root.left and ...

Comment: In a pre-order traversal you examine the parent node first.

Comment: yes, As I explained in that comment and also in the code @HunterMcMillen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public Node preOrderMod(Node temp)
{
    if (temp != null)
    {
        if (temp.left != null)
            return temp.left;

        if (temp.right != null)
            return temp.right;

        return mod(temp.parent);
    }

    return null;
}

private Node mod(Node temp)
{
    if (temp != null && temp != root)
    {
       if (temp.parent.left == temp && temp.parent.right != null)
          return temp.parent.right;

       return mod(temp.parent);
    }

    return null;
}
```

*For reference:*

> Pre-Order: root left right
>  In-Order: left root right
>   Post-Order: left right root

Comment: No,unfortunately It doesn't work. If we have a leaf that is right child the code above returns the leaf itself.

Comment: @Steve-p  No, It should  search for a parent that has a not_visited right child.

Comment: @SteveP. It should search for a parent that has a right child that has not visited. let me clarify my question: please imagine that we have a tree and we want to traverse it preOrder. So I want to write a function that take a node of the tree and return the node that should be  visited exactly the next in preOrder.

Comment: @SteveP. This code that you have written has problem when for example we have this numbers: 120,130,70,80,90,100. The order of these Nodes in preOrder traverse is this : 120,70,80,90,100,130. So when I call this function for 100 the function should return 130. But the code that you have written returns 90.

Comment: @Linda I think I understand what you want.  How does it look now?

Comment: @Linda No problem, glad we finally figured it out.